Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_4)/\Bbb Q(\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_3\alpha_4)$
Let $f\in\Bbb Q[x]$ be a quartic polynomial ($\deg f=4$) with Galois group $S_4$, and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4$ be its all roots, and $\beta:=\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_3\alpha_4$. I need to compute Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_4)/\Bbb Q(\beta)$.
Here is my attempt:
I know $S_4=\langle(1\,2),(1\,\dots\,4)\rangle$, so $G:=\mathrm{Gal}(\Bbb Q(\alpha_1\dots\alpha_4)/\Bbb Q)=\langle\sigma,\tau\rangle$, where $\sigma:\alpha_1\mapsto\alpha_2,\alpha_2\mapsto\alpha_1$ and $\tau:\alpha_1\mapsto\alpha_2\mapsto\dots\mapsto\alpha_1$.
Now I want to find enough elements in $G$ to generate $G'$ (the desired Galois group of $\Bbb Q(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_4)/\Bbb Q(\beta)$). For example, $\sigma\in G'$ is obvious. The first problem is I don't know the order of $G'$, i.e. I don't know how to compute $[\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q]$. The second one is I don't know how to find enough elements.
Any hint will be appreciated.

You can quickly find many elements of $G'$ if you remember that it is a subgroup of $S_4$, and also observe that $\tau^2=(13)(24)$ is in there. How many elements of $G'$ you get from this?

Anwered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3222054 in the comments, so cannot be marked as a duplicate, sigh...

More or less also answered by David here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1893654

The general story is told here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2696951 --- see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4172678

Ok found the abstract duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3018761 - I will let the OP and others decide if it's a sufficient one (based on what happened in the last days, in particular). Just to clarify what this means: even though the question is not the same, the method to obtain the answer is exactly the same (based on our assumption that the big extension has $S_4$ as the Galois group, which makes it "generic enough").

How I found all these: approach0 with search terms galois $X_1 X_2 + X_3 X_4$ dihedral (yeah I already knew the result hence the 3rd term). And I haven't even scrolled to the end!

@Martin Brandenburg Thank you for your detailed comments and 'approach0', that's an amazing search engine! I just realized it has little to do with galois theory but more a group theory problem and figured out 8 elements by careful counting. orbit-stablizer thm completes the count. But despite this, we surprisingly computed $\Bbb Q(\beta):\Bbb Q$ without finding minipoly :) I made too many duplicated questions recently, felt really sorry but I just cant find them by myself...

Adding the following piece that I think is missing from the answers to the duplicate targets Martin Brandenburg found. This step is not needed in this question because there the $\alpha_i$s are algebraically independent transcendental elements.

We can think of the Galois group $S_4$ acting on the subscripts of the $\alpha_i$'s. We see that $\beta$ is stabilized by the permutations $(12)$ as well as $(13)(24)$. Those two generate a copy of the dihedral group $D_4$ of the symmetries of a square. After all, if we number the corners of the square in the clockwise order $1,3,2,4$, those two permutation come from reflections with respect to two axes of symmetries with a $\pi/4$-angle in between, and hence generate all of $D_4$.
The group $D_4$ has index three in $S_4$, so it is a maximal subgroup. We just saw that $D_4\le G'$, so the remaining alternatives for $G'$ are $D_4$ and $S_4$. We need to rule out the possibility that $G'=S_4$. A simple argument for that is the following (surely can be found in every textbook deriving the formula for the roots of a quartic, but I did not find it annotated here).
If $G'=G=S_4$, then $\beta$ must also be stable under the action of a 3-cycle $(234)$ as well as its inverse. In other words, we get an extra identity
$$
\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_3\alpha_4=\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3.\qquad(*)
$$
Moving everything in $(*)$ to the left hand side and factoring, we arrive at
$$
(\alpha_1-\alpha_3)(\alpha_2-\alpha_4)=0.
$$
This means that there are repetitions among the roots $\alpha_i,i=1,2,3,4$. A known violation of properties of irreducible polynomials in characteristic zero.
So $G'=D_4$.

It is one of the key ideas in Galois theory that when the full symmetric group appearing as the Galois group, all the rational combinations of the roots must come from their elementary symmetric polynomials. Anyway, I felt that this detail was missing. And I'm largely unfamiliar with what's going on with specializations from transcendental extensions to finite ones.

Will happily delete (with a suitable set of duplicates), if others think that this piece is also covered.

In equation $(*)$, I believe there is a typo.

Indeed, thanks @JoshuaTilley.
